# SQL script with latest date

Tags: php

I am developing a invoice view system and I want to view single PDF invoice in iframe. I have no ideas how do I making SQL script that views single invoice with latest due date.

I am using Zend Framework and database is MySQL.

```
    public function viewinvoiceemployeeAction()
{
    /** Object variable. Example use: $logger->err("Some error"); */
    $logger = Zend_Registry::get('LOGGER');
    /** Object variable. Example use: $something = $config->database; */
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    /** Object variable. Example use: print $date->get(); */
    $date = Zend_Registry::get('date');
    /** Object variable. Example use: $stmt = $db->query($sql); */
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('dbAdapter');

    $request = $this->getRequest();

          $id = (integer) $request->getParam('ostoreskontra_id');
          $dateColumn = (string) date("Y-m-d", strtotime("NOW"));
          //select * from yourTable where dateColumn = (select max(dateColumn) from yourTable)

          $db->beginTransaction();

          try {

              $date = (string) date("Y-m-d", strtotime($db->fetchone("SELECT laskun_pvm FROM ostoreskontra WHERE laskunera_pvm = (SELECT MAX(".$db->quote($dateColumn, 'STRING').") FROM ostoreskontra);")));
              $number = (integer) $db->fetchone("SELECT laskun_nro FROM ostoreskontra WHERE laskunera_pvm = (SELECT MAX(".$db->quote($dateColumn, 'STRING').") FROM ostoreskontra);");
              $sublier = (string) str_replace(" ","+",$db->fetchone("SELECT toimittaja.nimi FROM ostoreskontra LEFT JOIN toimittaja ON ostoreskontra.toimittaja_id=toimittaja.toimittaja_id WHERE ostoreskontra.laskunera_pvm = (SELECT MAX(".$db->quote($id, 'STRING').") FROM ostoreskontra);"));

              $file = (string) $date.'_'.$sublier.'_'.$number.'.pdf';

              $db->commit();

              $content = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH."/uploads/ostolaskut/".$file);

              if ($id==0) {

                  header('Content-Type: text/plain');

              } else {

                  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                  header("Content-Length: " . strlen($content) );
                  //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);

                  echo $content;

              }

          } catch (Exception $e) {

          $db->rollBack();
          //$success = array('success' => false, 'msg' => $e->getMessage());
          echo $e->getMessage();

          }

          //print_r($name);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give us much information but... use this to get the last record in your table by date:

```
select * from yourTable where dateColumn = (select max(dateColumn) from yourTable)
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY dateColumn DESC LIMIT 1` is better

Comment: @Voitcus if there's only one record to retrieve. Not if there are many records for the same date.

Comment: You are right, but I was suggested by "single invoice" in the OP question.

Comment: ...and you've written "to get **the last record**". :-)